# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for my specific issue

Tags: python-3.x

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
def average(numbers):
        return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))

def get_average(student):
        return average(student["homework"]) * 0.1 + average(student["quizzes"]) * 0.3 + average(student["tests"]) * 0.6

def get_letter_grade(score):
        if (score >= 90.0):
            return "A"
        elif (score >= 80.0):
            return "B"
        elif (score >= 70.0):
            return "C"
        elif (score >= 60.0):
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"

def get_class_average(students):
        results = []
        for student in students:
            get_average(student)
            students.append(get_average(student))    
        return average(results)

print get_class_average(students)
print get_letter_grade(get_class_average(students))
```

I keep getting this error. Can some one look at it and let me know what i am doing wrong here. 
here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 45, in <module>
  File "python", line 41, in get_class_average
  File "python", line 24, in get_average
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: The least you could do would be to format your code. Also, did you research the error before asking?

Comment: Yes, I did do research. I am new to python still learning. It was difficult to relate the answers for my issue

Comment: And Andrew, I am not able to edit my question to format the code. sorry.

Comment: Highlight your code and press ctrl+k

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
students.append(get_average(student))
```

Before this line, `students` is a list of dictionaries. You are then appending the first average you compute to it, which is just a regular number. Then your program tries to call get_average on that number when it gets to it, resulting in the error you display above.

Either store the results in a different list, or set it as an entry on the `student` dictionary, don't append it to the `students` list.

Comment: Ah... Thank you! :) Fixed it.Thank you once again